# how to get next li and previous li using pure angular 2 no jquery

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have an array like this

```
this.tabMenuItems = [
        {
          "tabId":1,
          "item":"2017",
          "link":['/artists',this.artistId,'edit']  
        },
        {
          "tabId":2,
          "item":"2016" ,
          "link":['/artists',this.artistId,'edit'] 
        },
        {
          "tabId":3,
          "item":"2015" ,
          "link":['/artists',this.artistId,'edit'] 
        }
        
      ];
```

And i have a template bound this way ,as tabs

```
<

div class="tab-menu">   
      <ul>
          <li #tabMenuTemplate
              [routerLink]="menu.link" 
              [ngClass]="{'current': isActive(menu.link)}"
              class="tabmenu-{{index}}"
              *ngFor="let menu of tabMenuItems;let index = index"> {{menu.item}} </li>
      </ul>
    
      <button (click)="onNavMenuClick('left')" class="tab-left-arrow"></button>

  <button (click)="onNavMenuClick('right')"class="tab-right-arrow"></button>

</div>
```

I need to move to another tab if we click on next or previous button .I've tried to access this using template reference using  @ViewChild at component.

this way  `@ViewChild("tabMenuTemplate") tabMenuTemplate;`

```
var next =new ElementRef(this.tabMenuTemplate.nativeElement.nextSibling);
```

But couldn't get as expected . Please suggest which is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

you already have a array which you are looping to generate your tabs, you may simply use it to figure out which one you want to navigate to when you click next or previous, based on your current selection, you do not need to get the actual tab element.

so in  your next, back event, you may use `router.navigate()` to move to different link based on where are you in array.

Also you can make use of [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#routerlinkactive) to make the selected link active.

Here is a simple [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-get-next-li-and-previous-li-using-pure-angular-2-no-jque?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)!!

**Html**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let menu of tabMenuItems;let index = index" (click)="setTab(index)">
        <a [routerLink]="menu.link"  routerLinkActive="active-link">
            {{menu.item}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<button (click)="back()" [disabled]="selectedTab == 0">Previous</button>
<button (click)="next()" [disabled]="selectedTab == tabMenuItems.length-1">Next</button>
<hr />
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  tabMenuItems = [
    {
      "tabId": 1,
      "item": "child1",
      "link": ['/child1']
    },
    {
      "tabId": 2,
      "item": "child2",
      "link": ['/child2']
    },
    {
      "tabId": 3,
      "item": "child3",
      "link": ['/child3']
    }
  ];

  selectedTab = 0;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  setTab(index) {
    this.selectedTab = index;
  }

  next() {
    if (this.selectedTab < this.tabMenuItems.length) {
      this.selectedTab++;
      this.router.navigate(this.tabMenuItems[this.selectedTab].link);
    }
  }

  back() {
    if (this.selectedTab > 0) {
      this.selectedTab--;
      this.router.navigate(this.tabMenuItems[this.selectedTab].link);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will take a look